# Maven install slows down considerably when hitting "Applying concept 'java:VirtualDependsOn' with severity 'Minor"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am running maven install in the project module lifecycle within Intellij.
However, when it gets towards the end of the install, the run terminal shows the latest output as "Applying concept 'java:VirtualDependsOn".

My questions are what is "java:VirtualDependsOn" and what's a good way to help fix it, if that's possible.

Comment: Is it possible to share your pom.xml?

Comment: @y.bedrov unfortunely no. Since it is a company code base i am not able to share.

Comment: Is it reproducible with some sample project?